# Print multiple instances of same variable in BI Publisher

Tags: foreach, bi-publisher

I was actually trying to print multiple values of the same attribute `Title` with comma after each but couldn't remove comma after the last value which resulted in me writing complex loops.

Here I have initiated a count variable `storeCount` which increments and until it reaches the number of rows returned, I print `Title` and a comma that follows.
Here's my code. I am getting syntax error. I would appreciate help fixing the code.

```
<?for-each@inlines:G_1?>
    <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter') + 1)?>
    Title
    <?if@inlines:<?count(G_1)?> != <?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter')?>?>
        ,
    <?end-if?>
<?end for-each?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?for-each@inlines:G_1?>
    <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter', xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter') + 1)?>
    Title
    <?if@inlines:count(G_1) != xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCounter')?>
        ,
    <?end-if?>
<?end for-each?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should set the variable to 1 or something before the loop;
   Right now, you're essentially getting a non-existent variable and adding 1 to
   it on the first record.
2. You cant have  within an existing

Comment: Thanks, @EdHayes3. I initialized the counter variable: `<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'storeCount',0)?>` but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you cleaned up the code so that you don't have nested code snippets?  There should never be a <? after a <? unless there is a ?> in-between.